# Generic Real time server/client communication framework (Signalr on server(Classic asp.net(4.7.2) web api 2) and reactjs client)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I am trying to find out the best tech stack to use with the use-case described below

Server (asp.net 4.7.2 web api 2)
Client (reactjs)

I would like to have a real time server to client communication i.e. what signalr provides. Issue with using asp.net signalr is that it has dependency on jquery on the client side and we don't want that. Also, my client will be used by NodeJs server as well along with .Net Server. So, I would like to have a more generic approach on the client side to listen to the updates sent by either of those servers, with minimal or no code changes on the client

Keep in mind that the asp.net web api is in .net 4.7.2 and not .net core yet(hopefully in future).

For example can I use socket.io on the Reactjs side(client) and asp.net signalr on the Web API side(server)? Would this combination work, assuming Nodejs server will be able to talk to Socket.io on client without any issues?

If moving to .NET Core is not an option, then what else other than SignalR would be a  recommended solution here which is more generic/scalable and can work for other techs?

Any suggestions/working examples here are hugely appreciated.

Comment: Partial answer - the .NET 4.x client requires jquery. If you don't want that you have to move up to .NET CORE server and client. You cannot mix the server/client versions either. Check out - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-5.0#feature-differences

Comment: @FrankM - Thanks for the reply. So, if I move to .NET Core and implement signalr on the server and client, would the client side code support any other application with NodeJs on the server as well, without changes in the signalr specific code on the client(in my case ReactJs)?

Comment: I cannot answer, hence my partial answer above. I have only worked with using the clients where I build methods to be called.